# Rename 'main' thread in Rust

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, rust

I am working on an application that executes many processes, which at the same time use many threads. When something fails and the thread panics, rust outputs: `thread 'main' panicked at 'explicit panic'`. I would like to use this messages for debugging purposes, being able to identify the panicking process by its name, but in this case all processes have the 'main' thread name.

How can I change the main thread name?

I know I can change the name of a child thread using the `std::thread::Builder`, but this does not work for the current thread.

I have also tried using `pthread_setname_np` call (I am using a Linux system):

```rust
use libc::{pthread_self, pthread_setname_np};
use std::{ffi::CString, thread};

fn main() {

    // Set the name of the main thread
    let name = CString::new("new_name").unwrap();
    unsafe {
        pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), name.as_ptr());
    }

    panic!();
}
```

Executing this with `cargo run` still panics with the `main` name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is impossible: [the thread name is managed independently from the OS](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8a778ca1e35e4a8df95c00d800100d95e63e7722/library/std/src/sys_common/thread_info.rs#L8-L13), and [it is set](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8a778ca1e35e4a8df95c00d800100d95e63e7722/library/std/src/sys_common/thread_info.rs#L41-L47) only in two places in the standard library: [when setting up `main()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8a778ca1e35e4a8df95c00d800100d95e63e7722/library/std/src/rt.rs#L104-L105), and [when spawning a thread](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8a778ca1e35e4a8df95c00d800100d95e63e7722/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs#L524). There is no public API that changes it for the current thread (you can ask for one, if you believe this is important).

You can spawn a new thread and immediately `join()` it.

Comment: I see. I am spawning the processes from the main rust program. Is there any way to change the main thread name before spawning the process, before setting up main()? Or is it the same?

Comment: @javier Even more impossible, because you will need to access data that is private to the spawned process.

Answer (score 2):

One way to put detail on which process crashed is to set up a custom panic handler. A good example of this is in the Deno runtime:

https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/13145/files

Here's a short sample of how to do it:

```rust
fn main() {
    set_panic_hook(format!("Program {}", 1));
    panic!("something bad happened");
}

fn set_panic_hook(process_name: String) {
    let orig_hook = std::panic::take_hook();
    std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(move |panic_info| {
        eprintln!("\nPanic in process: {process_name}");
        orig_hook(panic_info);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }));
}
```

[Rust Playground Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ee543c758a81bd957506d772f64b45d)

Displays this output:

```
Panic in process: Program 1
thread 'main' panicked at 'something bad happened', src/main.rs:3:5
```

Comment: This answer solves my issue. Although, my question's title asks for how to rename the main thread. I will leave the accepted answer as is. Thank you very much, anyway. This was what I needed.